# select some field in database base on Check field on form php

Tags: php, yii2

I have table name  Checkin with fields : id,chief_compain, taking_history,pass_history,physical_exam and diagnosis.

i want use Checkbox Attribute on form as name of Field in a table " Checkin" , so after submit form will select only name of column have selected from database.

```
    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>
        <?= $form->field($model, 'id')->checkbox(['value'=>Yii::$app->request->get('id')]) ?>
         <?= $form->field($model, 'chief_compain')->checkbox(['value'=>'chief_compain']) ?>
        <?= $form->field($model, 'taking_history')->checkbox(['value'=>'taking_history']) ?>
        <?= $form->field($model, 'pass_history')->checkbox(['value'=>'pass_history']) ?>
        <?= $form->field($model, 'physical_exam')->checkbox(['value'=>'physical_exam']) ?>
        <?= $form->field($model, 'diagnosis')->checkbox(['value'=>'diagnosis']) ?>

    <div class="form-group text-center">
            <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Submit' : 'Save Update', ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-success']) ?>
        </div>
      <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>




    // === Controler 

    public function actionMedicalReport()
        {

            $model = new CheckIn();

            if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) ) {
                  $id=Yii::$app->request->post('id');
    $string = '';
            foreach (\Yii::$app->request->post() as $key => $value){
    if($value){
                    $string .= $key . ' ';
                    var_dump($string);
                }
            }

    $report=CheckIn::find()->select($string)->where(['id'=>$id])->all();
    return $this->render('print-report', ['report' => $report,]);

            } else {
                return $this->render('medical-report', [
                    'model' => $model,
                ]);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Your question for me isn't clear. What do you want exactly? Do you need a select dropdown? Have you read documentation about yii form and yii activerecords?

Comment: Hello Sfili_81. i don't want select dropdown. i want use Check Attribute on form as name of Field in a table " Doctor" , so after submit form will select only name of column have selected from database.  example : on form i check : names,phone so my query will be : SELECT names, phone FROM Doctor

Comment: Ok, but have you tried something? because your question seem like _i need the code_.... Do you have Model controller etc etc.

Comment: yes. i try some style, but not success so i have create a sample as above to ask for help. i have model and form in Yii. now i will post below.

Answer (score -1):

Ok, In Yii2 form you can not submit like this. You have to use ActiveForm widget or insert a hidden field with token, ovirwize you will get an Exception.
Second: if you pass your data throughout POST or GET you can easy check it using loop. Because you use checkbox, i assume that you pass throughout post and value is true or false.

```
$string = '';
foreach (\Yii::$app->request->post() as $key => $value){
    if($key !== '_csrf-backend' && $value){
        $string .= $key . ' ';
    }
}
```

after that you create your new Query and or you can implement that query before the loop and pass needed field in the loop. I strongly recommend to not use raw sql.

Comment: I have try as follow code but still god error;      Database Exception – yii\db\Exception
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '_csrf-backend' in 'field list'
The SQL being executed was: SELECT `_csrf-backend` AS `CheckIn` FROM `check_in` WHERE `id` IS NULL

Error Info: Array
(
    [0] => 42S22
    [1] => 1054
    [2] => Unknown column '_csrf-backend' in 'field list'
)

↵
Caused by: PDOException
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '_csrf-backend' in 'field list'

Comment: This "_csrf-backend" field allow you send request in Yii2 app, ovewize you will get an Bad Reqest. I Updated the Answer.

Answer (score -1):

**I have solved the problem. thanks all respond
now it work good**

```
1) Change name of field to array and use only 1 name
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'id')->checkbox(['value'=>Yii::$app->request->get('id')]) ?>
     <?= $form->field($model, 'chief_compain[]')->checkbox(['value'=>'chief_compain']) ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'chief_compain[]')->checkbox(['value'=>'taking_history']) ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'chief_compain[]')->checkbox(['value'=>'pass_history']) ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'chief_compain[]')->checkbox(['value'=>'physical_exam']) ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'chief_compain[]')->checkbox(['value'=>'diagnosis']) ?>

<div class="form-group text-center">
        <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Submit' : 'Save Update', ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-success']) ?>
    </div>
  <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

2) in Controller 

 $model = new CheckIn();

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) ) {
              $id=Yii::$app->request->post('id');
$string = '';
$post=$model->chief_compain;
        foreach ($post as $key ){
if($key)
{
               $string .=$key.' ';
   }             

        }
        $myval=str_replace(" ",",",trim($string));

$report=CheckIn::find()->select($string)->where(['id'=>$id])->all();
return $this->render('print-report', ['report' => $report,]);
```

Comment: Hello rob006, so can you give me some recommend to solve with the best way.

Comment: Some whitelist or proper validation. You should not blindy trust data from POST.